# vertically align DIV in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I am using Bootstrap 3 and need to vertically align a div to the center of the browser window (including on resize).

My current code is this...

```
<div class="container-liquid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img/video-camera.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="img/tablet.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="img/phone.png" alt="" > </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how I can vertically align the ROW and its items within a broswers window? Tried many different approaches but none work. I can use Jquery if that is an option.

The height of the largest image is 418px if that helps, but I'd rather set the images to be responsive so the height would change...

Comment: what's the css for `.container-liquid`? you can center that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to base it on the height of the window for resize. My approach is to:

css:

```
html, body{
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}

.container-liquid{
  height: 50%;
  padding: 25% 0%;
}
```

Html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container-liquid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img/video-camera.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="img/tablet.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="img/phone.png" alt="" > </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is the closest solution so far, but places my div 75% down the window screen - not the center...I am guessing it is adding the extra 25% to the top of the div which pushes it 25% past vertical center.

Comment: that's fine, just decrease the padding to perhaps 15%? You will have to play around with it a little cause I am not sure if you have a navbar or anything else. Also, if it's the closest solution, upvote or mark correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boatrokr/3bH45/1/

jquery is required - didn't read the question properly

```
 var blockTop = $('.container-liquid').height()/2 - $('.vertical-center-block').height();
 $('.vertical-center-block').css('top', blockTop);
```

Comment: is it centered now? check the fiddle again

Comment: the requires a fixed height for .container-liquid which rules out any responsiveness i have set for images. need a solution without a fixed height. I also cant' get it to work anyway. can you write the jquery command exactly how it should go in my html so i test please?